# Change size of views exposed form search box

Tags: 7, theming, views

Im using hook_preprocess_views_exposed_form to change the output of my views exposed search box.  I am able to successfully change the text on the search button, but I am not able to change the size.  I cant figure out where I am going wrong.  Here is what I have:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_exposed_form(&$vars, $hook) {
  // dsm($vars['form']);
  if ($vars['form']['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-all-page') {
    $vars['form']['submit']['#value'] = t('Go');
    $form['text']['#size'] = '90';
    unset($vars['form']['submit']['#printed']);
    $vars['button'] = drupal_render($vars['form']['submit']);
  }
}
```

This is what I am stuck on:

```
$form['text']['#size'] = '90';
```

Comment: `$form['text']` is it correct index?

Comment: Its $...['keys']['#size'], but I can get that to work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to change the form sooner than during themeing ... the best is to implement a form_alter hook, in this case

> function MODULENAME_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state)

you can try to dpm($form) first, to see what exactly you should change, and probably also add a condition about module id.

if you install [advanced_help](http://drupal.org/project/advanced_help), this info can be found on your site at help/views/alter-exposed-filter :)